# TSQL Text Comparison or Update Top 4000 rows of a query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm just now learning T-SQL and very familiar to Access trying to move over to SQL due to leads database size.

I know how to Select the Top 40000 rows, but I don't know how to update a field in the Query based on that.  So I tried to use a Less Than in the Phone field, but the issue is that the Phone number is a Text Field and won't work in SQL where it works in Access.  Any other ideas?

```
UPDATE tblLeadsCamp 
SET tblLeadsCamp.Subcampaign = @NewName
WHERE ((tblLeads.Phone)>'81455152') and tblLeads.Resi = 1
From tblLeads INNER JOIN tblLeadsCamp ON tblLeads.Phone = tblLeadsCamp.Phone)
```

Comment: Surely `WHERE ((tblLeads.Phone)>'81455152)'` should be `WHERE ((tblLeads.Phone)>'81455152')` - is that typo in your real code?

Comment: No that was me simplifying the query...  It Runs property, but doesn't update the fields.  I was assuming that SQL doesn't really accept Greater than or Less than for text fields the same way Access does.

Comment: Grumble Using Top 40000 Desc really select the top rows then sorted them instead so I was getting the wrong phone number to be less than.  Sorry was learning experience...

Answer (score 0):

To update top 4000 records you can simply do

```
UPDATE TOP(4000) tblLeadsCamp SET Subcampaign = @NewName
```

OR

Using your method -

```
UPDATE tblLeadsCamp 
SET tblLeadsCamp.Subcampaign = @NewName
From tblLeads INNER JOIN tblLeadsCamp ON tblLeads.Phone = tblLeadsCamp.Phone
WHERE CAST(CAST(tblLeads.Phone AS VARCHAR(10)) AS INT) > 81455152 and tblLeads.Resi = 1
```